# ffmpeg timestamp to logfile

Tags: ffmpeg, timestamp, media

How can I log the timestamp for each frame?

Command:

```
 ffmpeg -i movie.mp4 image%d.jpg -vstats -timestamp now
```

Log file:

```
root@chef-server:/home/user# cat vstats_111633.log
frame=     1 q= 1.8 f_size=  14964 s_size=       15kB time= 0.040 br=  2992.8kbits/s avg_br=  2992.8kbits/s type= I
frame=     2 q= 1.6 f_size= 150673 s_size=      162kB time= 0.080 br= 30134.6kbits/s avg_br= 16563.7kbits/s type= I
frame=     3 q= 1.6 f_size= 150794 s_size=      309kB time= 0.120 br= 30158.8kbits/s avg_br= 21095.4kbits/s type= I
frame=     4 q= 2.1 f_size= 150853 s_size=      456kB time= 0.160 br= 30170.6kbits/s avg_br= 23364.2kbits/s type= I
frame=     5 q= 4.4 f_size=  95332 s_size=      549kB time= 0.200 br= 19066.4kbits/s avg_br= 22504.6kbits/s type= I
frame=     6 q= 7.0 f_size=  65227 s_size=      613kB time= 0.240 br= 13045.4kbits/s avg_br= 20928.1kbits/s type= I
frame=     7 q= 9.8 f_size=  50215 s_size=      662kB time= 0.280 br= 10043.0kbits/s avg_br= 19373.1kbits/s type= I
```

So ideal would be to log the timestamp e.g 11:33:56

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In fact, the only way to check timestamps in such manner is to look at the value of the `time` column in the log file. These timestamps are represented in seconds. So the time stamp for the first frame is 0.040 sec, for the second - 0.080 sec and so on.

It's easy to see that the appearance of `time` column is not customizable.

To prove it let's look at the `do_video_stats` function from the `ffmpeg.c` file. This function is used to fill the contents of the log file. We can see the next line here:

```
fprintf(vstats_file, "s_size= %8.0fkB time= %0.3f br= %7.1fkbits/s avg_br= %7.1fkbits/s ", (double)ost->data_size / 1024, ti1, bitrate, avg_bitrate);
```

`time= %0.3f` is responsible for printing the timestamp. There're no options to modify the format because it's hardcoded inside the format string of `fprintf` function.

**EDIT**

As @LordNeckbeard mentioned, you can use `ffprobe` with `-sexagesimal` option:

```
ffprobe movie.mp4 -show_packets -sexagesimal
```

From the [docs](https://ffmpeg.org/ffprobe-all.html):

```
-show_packets

    Show information about each packet contained in the input multimedia stream.

    The information for each single packet is printed within a dedicated section with name "PACKET".

-sexagesimal

    Use sexagesimal format HH:MM:SS.MICROSECONDS for time values.
```

So `pts_time` in each `[PACKET][/PACKET]` section is a timestamp in `HH:MM:SS.MICROSECONDS` format.

Comment: Alright, so there is no way for me to log the time with the current timestamp? Or are there any possible hacks?

Comment: @user3580316 you already have timestamps in the `time` column. Is their format the only problem?

Comment: @user3580316 you can get similar results using `ffprobe` with `-show_packets` option. But time will be represented in seconds too...

Comment: @EdgarRokyan See `-sexagesimal` option in `ffprobe`.

Comment: @LordNeckbeard I think that it's exactly what OP wants. As an another variant OP can change the source code of `do_video_stats` function and build FFmpeg with this modification :)